# Setting Width and Height of a Constant node in NUKE

Tags: python, nodes, nuke

I am trying to link the `Read` node format of my input images to a `Constant` node down the tree as I am trying to process a bunch of images with varying resolutions and aspect ratios.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> dragging the format from the `Read` node to the `Constant` node to have it update if that is even a thing I can do.

I am fairly new to Nuke if you can't already tell.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to do what you need: Just create two nodes – `Read1` (with some content) and `Constant1` and execute the following code in NUKE's script Editor:

```
import nuke

sourceWidth = nuke.toNode("Read1").width() 
sourceHeight = nuke.toNode("Read1").height() 
nuke.tcl('add_format "%s %s temporaryResolution"' % (sourceWidth, sourceHeight)) 

nuke.toNode("Constant1").setSelected(True) 
nuke.createNode("Reformat")['format'].setValue('temporaryResolution')
```

Aa a result you'll get a `Reformat` node connected to `Constant1` with new width and height values.

Comment: I tried it and it seemed to work for the first image of the sequence of images, would this update with each resolution of the images?

Comment: It's irregular practice to use a sequence with different file resolution inside just one `Read` node. It's not manageable in compositing sense and scope. You need to use separate nodes `Read1`, `Read2`, `Read3`, etc. File sequence in NUKE must contain images of similar resolution. Your example just proves this state.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem entirely by just not using the `Constant` node, and instead make a blank image from your source imagery - that way it automatically inherits the input format.

Put differently, say you have something like so:

[image: Constant approach]

The constant has no input, therefore it has to specify a format - but all it does is make an empty image. What we want is a blank image but with the same format as the source image, so instead we can start with the source image, and simply remove all the channels (`Remove` node set to "channels: all"), then a Shuffle to recreate the default `rgba` layer. Something like so:

[image: Blanking pipe approach]

This way no scripting is required, so the problems of when the format-linking expressions are evaluated is avoided